# Question about stubbing method composed with other methods

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, stubbing

```
   def foo
     a & b & c & d
   end
```

And  it is very important for application logic, so I have to write good test for it. Methods a,b,c,d are already tested. Should I prepare full data to make a,b,c,d work and return requested values, or stubbing in this case is enougth?

Answer (score 1):

A unit test should only test the method under test, i.e. foo. This means, you should stub a, b, c and d.
To make it of any use, you should make sure, that you cover all corner cases that could result from the return values of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to test this thoroughly, I would write two kinds of automatic tests: a **unit test** which would receive a, b, c and d as stubs, and an **integration test** that would make sure all the logic works well together and there are no integration issues.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your desire to test thoroughly, but a unit test of this using stubs would only test that the `&` operator works properly.  That operator is not your code.

If you use mocks instead of stubs, it would at least test that all the methods are called, but that's really only sort of a documentation test.

An integration test using data might however be useful.

Comment: I assume, foo isn't really as simple as shown here. If it would be, it wouldn't be "very important for application logic". But *if* it were that simple, I would agree with you...